# "Package * does not exist" when running ant compile

Tags: java, ant

Using ant to compile (`ant compile`) a project where I have multiple src folders that need to be built each into their own classes folder.  Example:

```
.
|-- classes1/com
|   `-- A.class
|-- classes2/com
|   `-- B.class
|-- src1/com
|   `-- A.java
`-- src2/com
    `-- B.java
```

The problem that I'm running into is that B.java uses the class defined in A.java, and when compiling B.java it's throwing `package com.A does not exist`.

Here is what my ant snippet looks like:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.classes" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="src1" destdir="classes1" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
    <javac srcdir="src2" destdir="classes2" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

When I run `ant -v compile` I can even see classes1/com/A.class in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

First of all each compile has a slightly different classpath so keep them separate for clarity. Secondly jars are individually listed on a classpath whereas classes are referenced via their base directory.

Try the following:

```
<path id="compileA">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="compileB">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="classes1"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="src1" destdir="classes1" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="compileA"/>
    <javac srcdir="src2" destdir="classes2" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="compileB"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot that.
@Kyle Schustak, you might want to see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem **might** be the way the path `classpath` is being built. I suppose the dir "." is a folder that contains both `classes1` and `classes2`. In this case, the class "com.A" would be, indeed, "classes1.com.A".
The fileset should have two different paths (one for each folder), like:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="classes1">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="classes2">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This way, the base folders would be "classes1" and "classes2", instead of parent.